# DirectX 11 in only part of screen?

Tags: directx, viewport, rendertarget

I'm trying to set up a window where Direct X only participates in half of the screen.

My swap chain desc width is half screen, and my viewport width is half screen, but when I clear the render target to blue, the entire screen is blue rather than the half that I have designated for use.

Answer (score 3):

I know that it is old question, but anyway, if someone will come here from search:

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476388%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says:

> Differences between Direct3D 9 and Direct3D 11/10:
>
> Unlike Direct3D 9, the full extent of the resource view is always
>   cleared. Viewport and scissor settings are not applied.